# Spark Notebook not working on HUE for EMR

Tags: apache-spark, hue

Ok, I've got hue 3.8 pointing at my EMR cluster, and it's mostly working.  THe one thing I'm missing that I really care about at this point is spark notebook

when I attempt to choose a language for a snippet, there is an error, "`No usable value for lang Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String (error 400)`" and the logs say this:

```
[03/Jun/2015 11:38:59 -0700] decorators   ERROR    error running <function create_session at 0x7fe30acd1d70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/hue/apps/spark/src/spark/decorators.py", line 77, in decorator
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/hue/apps/spark/src/spark/api.py", line 44, in create_session
    response['session'] = get_api(request.user, snippet).create_session(lang=snippet['type'])
  File "/usr/local/hue/apps/spark/src/spark/models.py", line 284, in create_session
    response = api.create_session(kind=lang)
  File "/usr/local/hue/apps/spark/src/spark/job_server_api.py", line 87, in create_session
    return self._root.post('sessions', data=json.dumps(kwargs), contenttype='application/json')
  File "/usr/local/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/rest/resource.py", line 122, in post
    return self.invoke("POST", relpath, params, data, self._make_headers(contenttype, headers))
  File "/usr/local/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/rest/resource.py", line 78, in invoke
    urlencode=self._urlencode)
  File "/usr/local/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/rest/http_client.py", line 161, in execute
    raise self._exc_class(ex)
RestException: No usable value for lang
Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String (error 400)
```

Is this a problem with the software or my config?

THis might be tied to the fact that attempting to run `sudo ./hue livy_server` yields:

```
Failed to run spark-submit executable: java.io.IOException: 
  Cannot run program "spark-submit": error=2, No such file or directory
```

spark-submit does in fact exist and is in path

Answer (score 0):

The

> spark-submit

command comes from Spark, it needs to be present on the Hue machine.